# Key.chord or ActionSequence?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I need to simulate pressing `CTRL + C`, `CTRL + V`, and so on. Selenium give us two way to do it:
`webdriver.Key.chord(var_args)`, example:

```
webdriver.Key.chord(webdriver.Key.CONTROL, 'c')
```

and Class `ActionSequence`, example:

```
new webdriver.ActionSequence(driver).keyDown(webdriver.Key.CONTROL)
      .sendKeys('с')
      .keyUp(webdriver.Key.CONTROL);
action.perform();
```

Which way is better to use and why?

Comment: I think your second `keyDown` is a typo: surely `keyUp`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I am sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `webdriver.Key.chord` doesn't send any events, it simply [appends the arguments](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html#l1656) and adds a NULL on the end. According to the code:

> Note: when the low-level webdriver key handlers see Keys.NULL, active
>   modifier keys (CTRL/ALT/SHIFT/etc) release via a keyup event.

So assuming you pass the resulting string to `elem.sendKeys()`, you'll end up with:

```
 sendKeys: Ctrl-c
 keyUp: Ctrl
```

By contrast, using the Actions API in your example, you would get:

```
 explicit keyDown: Ctrl // *Not* released
 sendKeys: c
 explicit keyUp: Ctrl  // Note original edit had 'keyDown'
```

Which should give **exactly** the same result.

I'm sure `webdriver.Key.chord` is a more natural way to express the use of modifier keys, without anyone needing to think about key downs or ups, and ease of use is paramount. Even if 'performance' was slightly different, the difference isn't worth thinking about.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
If that and the other way to give *exactly* the same result, then really, it makes sense to use a simpler version.
And, as I understand it, ActionSequence need for playing a more complex combinations of actions, like, drag and drop, mouse clicks in combination with clamped modifier keys, and so on.